# amCharts categoryAxis dateFormats (v3) not working

Tags: amcharts

The code below works fine:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
}
```

But fails when I add the "dateFormats" line below:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "dateFormats": [{period:'DD',format:'DD MMM'},{period:'WW',format:'DD MMM'}]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) make sure all possible periods are defined. You currently have only daily ("DD") and weekly ("WW").

Even if your data is all daily, the chart still displays other period formats, such as year ("YYYY") to indicate beginning of the year or a month on category axis labels. I.e.:

**2014** | 2014 Jan | 2014 Feb | ...

So at the very least you should add "YYYY" and "MM" in `dateFormats`:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "dateFormats": [{period:'DD',format:'DD MMM'},{period:'MM',format:'DD MMM'}, {period:'YYYY',format:'DD MMM'}]
}
```

I don't think "WW" is needed, unless you have weekly data.

UPDATE: just realized you probably need "MM" as well.